# Product creation using shopify gem returns 404 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify

I'm trying to use the shopify_api gem to add products to a shop. Here is the code that I'm trying to use to do this:

```
ShopifyAPI::Base.authenticate
variant_shopify = ShopifyAPI::Variant.create(
                          :compare_at_price => @variant.compare_at_price,
                          :created_at => @variant.created_at,
                          :fulfillment_service => @variant.product.vendor.fulfillment_service.name,
                          :grams => @variant.grams,
                          :id => @variant.id,
                          :inventory_management => @variant.inventory_management,
                          :inventory_policy => @variant.inventory_policy,
                          :inventory_quantity => @variant.inventory_quantity,
                          :price => @variant.price,
                          :requires_shipping => @variant.requires_shipping,
                          :sku => @variant.sku,
                          :taxable => @variant.taxable,
                          :title => @variant.title,
                          :updated_at => @variant.updated_at)
product_shopify = ShopifyAPI::Product.create(
                          :body_html => @product.body_html,
                          :created_at => @product.created_at,
                          :id => @product.id,
                          :images => [{ :src => @product.image.url }],
                          :product_type => @product.product_type,
                          :published_at => @product.published_at,
                          :template_suffix => @product.template_suffix,
                          :title => @product.title,
                          :updated_at => @product.updated_at,
                          :variant => variant_shopify,
                          :vendor => @product.vendor.business_name)
```

However this code results in a 404 response from shopify. Any ideas on what I could do? Thanks for the help in advnace

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes little sense. Let's take your product create statement to start with. You are trying to create a product using a hash. Fine. Why are your hash parameters a product instance variable? Ok.. leaving that aside, when you create a product, you get an ID, from API. Additionally, it provides a timestamp for the created_at date. A create is not an update so you do not provide that.

Assuming you grabbed an existing product for @product, you would then be needing to feed not only the parameters from that that matter, but also you'd have to provide a unique handle. Strip it down to fixing that first, and all else will follow.

Comment: I'm creating a completely new project. The product instance variable is an object populated from a field. Is there a way to let shopify generate this handle, or should I generate it and fill it myself?

Comment: Take a minute and see how Shopify does it. Follow their pattern. It works.

Comment: I meant to say product instead of project in that first sentence. Maybe that lead to some sort of misunderstanding, but I don't really know what you mean when you say "how Shopify does it," nor do I really know where to get this information. The official API page mainly deals in how to interface with shopify with POST and GET requests, but doesn't really speak on how to use the gem, whereas there don't seem to be any resources on how to use the gem to create completely new products. If you know what links I should be looking at, those would be immensely helpful.

Comment: Open up your test/development shop and add a product using that. You'll be able to create a minimum viable product which you can then read with your App. Examine the returned product, and you'll be able to then reverse the procedure and create a brand new one.

It makes no sense to me to try and develop an App without having at least a development shop at your disposal. They're free and it takes less than minute to setup one.